# How to remove unwanted characters in a file (using a shell script)

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a file which looks like this (file.txt)

```
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr44  CRITICAL","component  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr45  CRITICAL","component  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr46  CRITICAL","component  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr47  CRITICAL","component  MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com     CODE_SMELL
AYOnanmeknsgv2StRr48  MAJOR",               MMP-FileService  gbhasrajkn@vir.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanm-knsgv2StRr4-  BLOCKER",             MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com      CODE_SMELL
AYOnanm6knsgv2StRr49  MAJOR",               MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com      CODE_SMELL
AYOnannKknsgv2StRr4_  BLOCKER",             MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com   BUG
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqkr  MINOR",               MMP-FileService  sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqkt  MINOR",               MMP-FileService  sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqks  MINOR",               MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqku  MINOR",               MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODsI7Fknsgv2StRqac  MAJOR",               MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODsI7Nknsgv2StRqad  MAJOR",               MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODsI-Qknsgv2StRqai  MAJOR",               MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
```

I have to remove unwanted characters in 2nd column
`","component` and `",`

then expected output

```
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr44  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr45  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr46  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr47  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com    CODE_SMELL
AYOnanmeknsgv2StRr48  MAJOR     MMP-FileService  gbhasrajkn@vir.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanm-knsgv2StRr4-  BLOCKER   MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com    CODE_SMELL
AYOnanm6knsgv2StRr49  MAJOR     MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com    CODE_SMELL
AYOnannKknsgv2StRr4_  BLOCKER   MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com    BUG
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqkr  MINOR     MMP-FileService  sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqkt  MINOR     MMP-FileService  sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqks  MINOR     MMP-component  sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqku  MINOR     MMP-component  sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODsI7Fknsgv2StRqac  MAJOR     MMP-component  sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODsI7Nknsgv2StRqad  MAJOR     MMP-component  sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODsI-Qknsgv2StRqai  MAJOR     MMP-component  sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
```

This is what I tried

```
cat file.txt | tr -d '",' | sed 's/component//'
```

then output I got

```
YOnanl3knsgv2StRr44  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr45  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr46  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr47  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com     CODE_SMELL
AYOnanmeknsgv2StRr48  MAJOR               MMP-FileService  gbhasran@virtusa.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanm-knsgv2StRr4-  BLOCKER             MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com      CODE_SMELL
AYOnanm6knsgv2StRr49  MAJOR               MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com      CODE_SMELL
AYOnannKknsgv2StRr4_  BLOCKER             MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com   BUG
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqkr  MINOR               MMP-FileService  sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqkt  MINOR               MMP-FileService  sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqks  MINOR               MMP-    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqku  MINOR               MMP-    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODsI7Fknsgv2StRqac  MAJOR               MMP-    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODsI7Nknsgv2StRqad  MAJOR               MMP-    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODsI-Qknsgv2StRqai  MAJOR               MMP-    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
```

my executed shell command is applying to the other columns as well (in this case it has applied to 3rd column too) that is the problem I am having. Is there any way to apply command only for
2nd column?

Can someone help me to figure out this? Thanks in advance!

**Note: I am not allowed to use jq or other scripting languages as JavaScript, Python etc.**

Comment: Remove `","component` first then remove `",` - that way you won't accidentally remove 'component'

Comment: `cat file.txt | sed -e 's/","component//' -e 's/",//'`

Comment: I would do it in `awk`, because this makes it trivial to work on only one of the columns; but I wonder if the bizarre anathema agains "other scripting languages" also includes awk ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this approach, if you are sure the characters you wish to remove appear in the second column only (borrowed and adapted from here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492500/awk-replace-one-character-only-in-a-certain-column)

```
awk '{{gsub("\",(\"component)?","", $2)}} 1' file.txt
```

- `gsub("\",\"component?","", $2)` for each input line, replace all the `",("component)?` in 2nd field with blank - this is a regular expression saying find `",` then optionally the part in brackets: `"component`. `?` is the operator for optional
- `1` is an awk idiom to print contents of `$0` (which contains the input record)

Comment: Useless Use Of Cat. Awk can parse file itself without pipe

Comment: @mjsqu Thank you! I am wondering is there any way to increase column space with this awk command? or do I have to use another command to increase the column space? this gives 1 space between columns

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in a single `sub`:

```bash
awk '{sub(/"[^[:blank:]]*$/, "", $2)} 1' file | column -t

AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr44  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr45  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr46  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr47  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com    CODE_SMELL
AYOnanmeknsgv2StRr48  MAJOR     MMP-FileService  gbhasrajkn@vir.com   CODE_SMELL
AYOnanm-knsgv2StRr4-  BLOCKER   MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com    CODE_SMELL
AYOnanm6knsgv2StRr49  MAJOR     MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com    CODE_SMELL
AYOnannKknsgv2StRr4_  BLOCKER   MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com    BUG
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqkr  MINOR     MMP-FileService  sam.curren@wt.com    CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqkt  MINOR     MMP-FileService  sam.curren@wt.com    CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqks  MINOR     MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com    CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqku  MINOR     MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com    CODE_SMELL
AYODsI7Fknsgv2StRqac  MAJOR     MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com    CODE_SMELL
AYODsI7Nknsgv2StRqad  MAJOR     MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com    CODE_SMELL
AYODsI-Qknsgv2StRqai  MAJOR     MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com    CODE_SMELL
```

Here:

- `"[^[:blank:]]*$`: Matches text starting with `"` in input (`$2`) and we replace it with an empty string.
- `column -t` is used for tabular output only that you can remove if you don't want.

Comment: this works. `column -t ` this was a thing I was searching for make column space. it is useful. thank you

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** Considering that your string `","component` will come always kin same place please try following `awk` code. This code will preserve the spaces also between the fields as per shown samples only.

```bash
awk '
match($0,/","*[^[:space:]]*/){
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) sprintf("%-"(RLENGTH) "s",OFS) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** with GNU `awk` using `match` function along with regex which does considers that your string will come in 2nd field only as per shown samples, this also takes care of spaces in Input_file and preserves them in output. Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ypVo23/1) for used regex.

```bash
awk '
match($0,/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+)([^"]*)(","*[^[:space:]]*)(.*$)/,arr){
  print arr[1] arr[2] sprintf("%-"length(arr[3]) "s",OFS) arr[4]
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I checked both answers. but it removed unwanted characters only with "CRITICAL" word. in this column other words come up with unwanted characters like MAJOR",  BLOCKER", I have to remove unwanted characters in all rows of 2nd column.

Comment: @Zero5, Please check my 2nd solution once its Fixed. I am fixing 1st solution till now, cheers. Will let you know once I am done with fixing 1st solution.

Comment: @Zero5, I have fixed both the solutions now, please do check them once and let me know how it went, cheers.

Comment: Now both answers work fine. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

You might use GNU sed for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr44  CRITICAL","component  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr45  CRITICAL","component  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr46  CRITICAL","component  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr47  CRITICAL","component  MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com     CODE_SMELL
AYOnanmeknsgv2StRr48  MAJOR",               MMP-FileService  gbhasrajkn@vir.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanm-knsgv2StRr4-  BLOCKER",             MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com      CODE_SMELL
AYOnanm6knsgv2StRr49  MAJOR",               MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com      CODE_SMELL
AYOnannKknsgv2StRr4_  BLOCKER",             MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com   BUG
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqkr  MINOR",               MMP-FileService  sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqkt  MINOR",               MMP-FileService  sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqks  MINOR",               MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqku  MINOR",               MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODsI7Fknsgv2StRqac  MAJOR",               MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODsI7Nknsgv2StRqad  MAJOR",               MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODsI-Qknsgv2StRqai  MAJOR",               MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
```

then

```
sed 's/"[^[:space:]]*//' file.txt
```

gives output

```
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr44  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr45  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr46  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  James.curren@wt.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanl3knsgv2StRr47  CRITICAL  MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com     CODE_SMELL
AYOnanmeknsgv2StRr48  MAJOR               MMP-FileService  gbhasrajkn@vir.com  CODE_SMELL
AYOnanm-knsgv2StRr4-  BLOCKER             MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com      CODE_SMELL
AYOnanm6knsgv2StRr49  MAJOR               MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com      CODE_SMELL
AYOnannKknsgv2StRr4_  BLOCKER             MMP-FileService  nipun.dith@wt.com   BUG
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqkr  MINOR               MMP-FileService  sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqkt  MINOR               MMP-FileService  sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqks  MINOR               MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODwmuBknsgv2StRqku  MINOR               MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODsI7Fknsgv2StRqac  MAJOR               MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODsI7Nknsgv2StRqad  MAJOR               MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
AYODsI-Qknsgv2StRqai  MAJOR               MMP-component    sam.curren@wt.com   CODE_SMELL
```

Explanation: replace first `"` and all subsequent non-whitespace characters using empty string, i.e. delete it. Assumption: `"` does appear only in 2nd column and you do not need to keep columns aligned.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.2.2)*